# PHP error logging - can I log all ofg the site's error to a single file?

Tags: php, logging

in PHP.INI, I can set the variable "error_log" and it is currently set to "error_log", which manes one file of that name in each directory

Do you know ... if I set it to "public_html/error_log" - will I get only one single error log file?  Any other way to do so? I really just want a single site-wide error file to check, rather than one on each sub-directory.

For bonus marks, can I send myself an email each time a new entry is added to the file?

Left as an exercise for the reader - can I ignore some "errors" which aren't really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running PHP under Apache, you can set php directives in `.htaccess` file, so per site or even per directory, see http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) and set it to a function which logs it to a file (and ignores certain types of errors if you like), and sends the email

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  // check if we want to log the error
  // log the error
  // send the mail
}

set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

Comment: I always use a custom error handler, so this is a good suggestion. However, I wouldn't send email from within an error handler – I commented on this in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes, that should work.

As far as email is concerned, **knittl** gave a correct answer but there are risks. 1 – you could end up with an email flood, 2 – it may slow page delivery down because some email sending methods in PHP take a few seconds to return control to the calling script, which is an issue if it hasn't already sent its results to the client.

If you want email notifications, you could consider an alternative approach, e.g. a script run by cron that emails you if the log has been written to since it last ran. That resolves both issues and you can control the maximum rate of emails by the frequency at which the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying an absolute path for the error_log, such as

```
/var/logs/php.err
```

in php.ini will make that the default system-wide php error logfile. You can then do per-server/per-directory logging by putting override error_log directives into the appropriate virtual host/directory settings (e.g. site.conf Apach files, .htaccess, etc...) if you need to log specific areas differently.